# No associated value for contextual member

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicolor

I have this line of code that I´m using

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

But I´m getting this error:

> Contextual member 'redColor' has no associated value.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Is that error coming from that specific line of code?

Comment: @rmaddy, no just trying to change a views background color. Also tried view.backgroundColor...

Answer (score 2):

The syntax has been changed in Swift 3.0:

From `UIColor.grayColor()` to `UIColor.gray`

You could also use `self.backgroundColor = .gray`